# Enabling SSL on site and broken links

Tags: php, html, apache, ssl, https

I have enabled SSL on my site and it has broken links like these, as they are still invoked on `HTTP` by the browser:

```
<script src="/some_JS_library/some_js_minified.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/some_JS_library/some_js_stylesheet.min.css" />
```

These links are in the landing page, such as `https://example.org/folder/landingpage.php` where `landing page.php` is in this directory structure relative to the scripts.

Of course, all this works perfectly fine in `HTTP`, but breaks in `HTTPS` due to the **insecure content** fetched using `HTTP` not being allowed to run (Safari 9+).

```
Root
 - folder
   |- landingpage.php 

 - some_JS_library
   |- some_js_minified.min.js
   |- some_js_stylesheet.min.css
```

What change in these links could make it work for `HTTPS` and `HTTP`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use protocol relative links (two slashes in beginning):

//some_url.com/some_file.js

//somefolder/somefile.js

Comment: I have tried but it breaks, especially since the `.js` and `.css` are not in the same folder as the `.php`, it is `../some_JS_library`, but then how to attach `//` to such a path?